# Where can i find the version of the Google Calendar API?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I want to use the Google Calendar API for my Android Studio Project. I have to include this in my Gradle.File

```
 compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-<API>-<VERSION>') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
```

But i can´t find anywhere the Google Calendar Api "Version"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most actuate location for that information would probably be the discovery api and then the link to the direct discovery file for that api

```
https://discovery.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis
```

Which would give you the following information

```
{
  "kind": "discovery#directoryItem",
  "id": "calendar:v3",
  "name": "calendar",
  "version": "v3",
  "title": "Google Calendar API",
  "description": "The Google Calendar API lets you manage your calendars and events.",
  "discoveryRestUrl": "https://calendar-json.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v3",
  "icons": {
    "x16": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_16dp.png",
    "x32": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_32dp.png"
  },
  "documentationLink": "http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/",
  "preferred": true
},
```

You could then go as far as double checking the discoveryRestUrl for that api.

```
https://calendar-json.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v3
```

Which contains the flowing entries which i would assume you would be able to use in your library

```
"name": "calendar",
"version": "v3"
```